# Network error message: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0

Tags: node.js, port, create-react-app

Whenever I try to run any of my create-react-app projects locally using npm start/yarn start, I keep getting this same error. It was working perfectly fine a couple days ago but randomly this error started popping up.

Could not find an open port at 0.0.0.0.
Network error message: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0

I have tried restarting windows multiple times, reinstalling node, running in sudo, checking if the ports are in use but none of them resulted in the error getting fixed. This is happening with every create-react-app project and every port, even happening with new projects.